# How to increse the size of td1 whout affecting td2?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I am work on outlook designing in my menu page.
In that I have done the drag the `td` and height of `td (id="leftContent")` is increase, but problem is when I increase the height of `td (id="leftContent")` then automatically increase the height of `td2(id="RightContent")`.
So how to increse the the height of only left `td` without affecting the right content.
My sample table code

```
<table> 
     <tr>
          <td id="leftContent"></td> <!--This is just sample code because original code is very long and in left and right -->
          <td id="RightContent"></td> <!--content have many table and TD and tr-->
     </tr>
</table>
```

This is the table html markup.

I tried to solve this problem by taking both `td` in separate `div` tags
as following:

```
<div>
    <td id="leftContent">
<div>
<div>
    <td id="RightContent">
<div>
```

but this did not even work .

I tried to change position like absolute, relative, static, and fixed, apply all the property to right content but when I drag the `td` then automatically increasing the height of right content with left content.

Comment: 12 questions and not one of them marked answered.

Comment: You html markup is wrong. It should be <td id="leftContent">This is just a sample</td>

Comment: @paulslater19 I think he's just adding it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

This is just the way tables work. `td`s within a given `tr` are always the same height.

(I assume that the lack of closing tags in your example is just an oversight.)